# Missing Results from Recordset

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm having an issue when I create a recordset object in classic asp where my recordset object does not recognize the correct number of results.

My code:

```
subProdQuery = "SELECT idProduct, idSupplier FROM products WHERE pcprod_ParentPrd="&prodID&";"
subRes = conn.execute(subProdQuery)
if subRes.BOF and subRes.EOF then
    response.write subProdQuery&"<br>"&subRes("idProduct")&"LAST ENTRY<br>"
else
    do until subRes.EOF
        response.write subRes("idProduct")&"<br>"
        subRes.MoveNext
    loop
end if
set subRes = nothing
```

The results I'm getting are very strange.  If I manually type the generated queries into SQL management studio, I get at least 5 results for each.  When generating the results via asp, subRes is always recognized as being both BOF and EOF.  However, the result of printing subRes("idProduct") in each case is the first result that I expect for each query.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is in "if" condition. When you use BOF or EOF in a condition you'll have called BOF or EOF condition. Try to do a test. Remove your if condition and just do your EOF looping. I know if is necessary, but try to do it.

Comment: It loops til timeout, the same "idProduct" is generated more times than I can count

Comment: What is the value of MaxRecords and RecordCount in your record set object?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, protect against SQL injection and use an ADODB.Command with parameters. At least, if ProdID is an int, validate it first.

You sometimes need a call to MoveFirst to set the BOF/EOF flags. It is sufficient to check for EOF only if you are moving forwards only.

```
on error resume next
Dim inttest
inttest = CLng(prodID)
if err.number > 0 then ... <<< do something about invalid inputs
on error goto 0

subProdQuery = "SELECT idProduct, idSupplier FROM products WHERE pcprod_ParentPrd=" & prodID
subRes = conn.execute(subProdQuery)

subRes.MoveFirst ' << add this
if subRes.EOF then
    response.write subProdQuery&"<br>"&subRes("idProduct")&"LAST ENTRY<br>"
else
    do until subRes.EOF
        response.write subRes("idProduct")&"<br>"
        subRes.MoveNext
    loop
end if
set subRes = nothing
```

Instead of ADOConnection.Execute, I normally use [ADOConnection.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows more options.

```
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Dim subRes = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
subRes.Open subProdQuery, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adUseClient
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I did what you suggested and the if is still always hitting (subRes.EOF is always true), and just the first result is printed, even though the same query is generating 5 results on server management studio.

Comment: How about using ADOConnection.Open?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `set` .

`set subRes = conn.execute(subProdQuery)`